# Changing abbreviations for strings

Tags: python

Trying to change the abbreviated addresses end with full description but the traceback does not make any sense. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

```
import pandas as pd

edit = pd.read_csv('mycsvfile')

edit['Home'] = edit['Home'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('Ct', 'Court'))
edit['Home'] = edit['Home'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('Rd', 'Road'))
edit['Home'] = edit['Home'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('Ln', 'Lane'))

edit.to_csv('newcsvfile',index = False)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\.py", line 20, in <module>
edit['Home'] = edit['Home'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('Ct', 'Court'))
File "C:\********.py", line 2294, in apply
mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1207, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:66124)
File "C:******.py", , in <lambda>
edit['Home'] = edit[Home'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('Ct', 'Court'))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

These are few of the values in the Home column:

```
1458 Clearlight Rd
7458 Grove Ln
8574 Grove Ct
2222 Grove Ln
1258 Grove Ct
1478 Grove Ln
```

Comment: This can only be found out by looking at the actual data in `yourcsvfile`.

Comment: It is all addresses. The traceback does not even point at any specific row in the csv file.

Comment: pandas parsed `Home` column as float, not as string. Please post sample of the input data.

Comment: Sample posted, please have a look at it.

Comment: Try `print(edit['Home'])` and see if you are right with the assumption that those strings are in the Home column.

Comment: It printed all of the 953 addresses. Name: Home, dtype: object

Comment: Are you sure that header line is correct?

Please post few full lines with header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the values in the Home column are missing. Pandas treats missing values as numpy nan, which are of type float.

You have a few options:

1. Fill your missing values with something other than that np.nan: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html
   (Fill missing values when reading csv: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
2. Filter for non-null values, then apply your function:

`edit[edit['Home'].notnull()]['Home'].apply(lambda s: s.replace('Ct', 'Court')`